# What is the proper format for a JSON Response?

Tags: java, python, json, response

I've worked with several different APIs where I needed to parse JSON.  And in all cases the Response is constructed a bit differently.

I now need to expose some data via a JSON API and want to know the proper way to deliver that Response.

Here is an example of what I have now, however some users (one using Java) are having difficulty parsing.

```
    {"status": "200 OK", 
    "code": "\/api\/status\/ok", 
    "result": {
      "publishers": ["Asmodee", "HOBBITY.eu", "Kaissa Chess & Games"], 
      "playing_time": 30, "description": "2010 Spiel des Jahres WinnerOne player is the storyteller for the turn. He looks at the 6 images in his hand. From one of these, he makes up a sentence and says it out loud (without showing the card to the other players).The other players select amongst their 6 images the one that best matches the sentence made up by the storyteller.Then, each of them gives their selected card to the storyteller, without showing it to the others. The storyteller shuffles his card with all the received cards. ",   
      "expansions": ["Dixit 2", "Dixit 2: \"Gift\" Promo Card", "Dixit 2: The American Promo Card", "Dixit Odyssey"], 
      "age": 8, 
      "min_players": 3, 
      "mid": "\/m\/0cn_gq3", 
      "max_players": null,  
      "designers": ["Jean-Louis Roubira"], 
      "year_published": 2008, 
      "name": "Dixit"
      }
    }
```

The Java user in particular is complaining that they get the error:

org.json.JSONException:[json string] of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

But in Python I am able to take in this Response, fetch "result" and then parse as I would any other JSON data.

*** UPDATE ***

I passed both my JSON and Twitter's timeline JSON to JSONLint.  Both are valid.  The Java user can parse Twitter's JSON but not mine.  What I noticed with Twitter's JSON is that it's encapsulated with brackets [], signifying an array.  And the error this user is getting with my JSON is that it cannot be converted to a JSON array.  I didn't think I need to encapsulate in brackets.

Comment: THat error implies they are trying to convert it to array, while it isn't one? Could you show what they are doing when getting this error?

Comment: Good question - will get the answer.  But you don't see anything wrong with this Response format correct?  I notice that Twitter, formats their Response as [{key: value, key, value}].  Notice the encapsulating brackets.  This User says he has not problem parsing Twitter's JSON.

Comment: If you look at the [JSON page](http://www.json.org/), an array is defined as `[elements]` where `elements` can be an `object` (which is what your example with Twitter shows) or `string | number |array | true | false | null` which is what your JSON response example shows. I agree with @Nanne, you need to check with your user and see what he's doing because your JSON seems to be valid and so it's your user who isn't using it correctly.

Comment: OK I will follow up with more questions - thanks!

Comment: Also no.good.at.coding - you answered my confusion about how JSON defines an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks valid according to http://json.parser.online.fr/ (random json parser). Its in the other code i'd say ;)

Comment: I've put it back in the other court.  I believe the user is incorrectly parsing by using JSONArray.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly are you generating this response? Are you doing it yourself?

I see you have a dangling comma at the end of the last element in `publishers` (i.e. after the value `Kaissa Chess & Games`).

I'd recommend using [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com) to ensure your JSON is valid.

Comment: Good eye.  That was a cut and paste mistake - fixed.